# Equation incl. number on the same line as theorem environment

Tags: spacing, equations, theorems

I have this:

```
\begin{lemma}
 \begin{equation} 
   L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.
 \end{equation}
\end{lemma}
```

and I would like the equation to be on the same line as the lemma, with a number label.
Adding `\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}` doesn't work.
How can it be solved?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would avoid such a layout: a statement consisting of an equation only is incomplete. Either add some words about the hypotheses, or just state the equation without calling it “Lemma”. You can refer to it by the equation number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually set this very specific requirement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
Some regular text.
\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}
Here is a break of some more text.
\begin{lemma}
\begin{equation}
  L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.
\end{equation}
\end{lemma}
Another break of regular text.

\medskip
\refstepcounter{lemma}%
\noindent\leavevmode\rlap{\textbf{Lemma~\thelemma.}}\hfill%
$L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.$\hfill%
\refstepcounter{equation}%
\llap{(\theequation)}\par%
\medskip

Some final text.
\end{document}
```

`\medskip` seemed sufficient in terms of the spacing. However, if need be, one can dig through the code and find the exact vertical spacing above/below the `lemma` to make it identical to the rest.

The overlapping (`\rlap` and `\llap`) is to make sure the equation is eventually centred when using `\hfill`.

Comment: Fine, it works. But how complicated has all this become...

Comment: @Gerard: I don't know what to say... you want something out of the ordinary... then expect something out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 4):

One can also define a `centredequ` environment that centres the equation in the remaining free part of the current line. It works with the `cleveref` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage{cleveref} 
\newcounter{centredequ}
\newenvironment{centredequ}{\refstepcounter{equation}\hfill\begin{math}}{\end{math}\hfill$(\theequation)$\par\noindent}
\crefname{centredequ}{eq.}{eqs. }
\Crefname{centredequ}{Eq.}{Eqs. }

\begin{document}

First a displayed equation: 
\begin{equation}\label{disp}
  a = b
\end{equation}
Some regular text with a centred equation: \begin{centredequ}\label{taut}
  a' = b'.
\end{centredequ}
\Cref{taut} is almost the same as \cref{disp}. 

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}
Here is a break of some more text.

\begin{lemma}\label{lem2}
\begin{centredequ}L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.\label{com}\end{centredequ}%
\end{lemma}
As we can see from \cref{taut} and \cref{lem2}, \cref{com} …

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Technically the equation won't be centered using this method, as is displayed in equation (2). But that may be sufficient for the OP. It's noticeable when you have the same equation just above/below **Lemma 2**.

Answer (score 2):

The earlier answer using `centredeq` does not truly center the equation with respect to the whole text block, but rather centers with respect to the remaining space on the line. The other answer fixes this but essentially redefines the lemma environment.

If you don't want to redefine environments, one solution is to `\clap` (or `\mathclap`) the equation you want to center. Here's the code:

```
\begin{lemma}\stepcounter{equation}%
\hfill$\mathclap{L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.}$%
\hbox{\hspace{0.5\textwidth}\llap{(\theequation)}}
\end{lemma}
```

The results, and the results with explanations:
[image]

---

**Edit:** I created four specialized environments `alignsameline`, `alignsameline*`, `eqsameline` and `eqsameline` for reusability. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\NewEnviron{alignsameline}{%
\stepcounter{equation}%
\hfill\clap{$\begin{aligned}[t]\relax %
\BODY%
\end{aligned}$}\hskip0.5\linewidth\hbox{\llap{\textnormal{(\theequation)}}}\vskip1\belowdisplayskip%
}

\NewEnviron{alignsameline*}{%
\hfill\clap{$\begin{aligned}[t]\relax %
\BODY%
\end{aligned}$}\hskip0.5\linewidth\hbox{}\vskip1\belowdisplayskip%
}

\NewEnviron{eqsameline}{%
\stepcounter{equation}%
\hfill\clap{$\displaystyle %
\BODY%
\relax$}\hskip0.5\linewidth\hbox{\llap{\textnormal{(\theequation)}}}\vskip1\belowdisplayskip%
}

\NewEnviron{eqsameline*}{%
\hfill\clap{$\displaystyle %
\BODY%
\relax$}\hskip0.5\linewidth\hbox{}\vskip1\belowdisplayskip%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
    \begin{eqsameline}
        L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.
    \end{eqsameline}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Shouldn't that be `\llap{(\theequation)}` in the code to agree with the explicated visual?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's true! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX and was writing up this answer partly for my own future reference. I'm surprised that even an answer to such an old question is greeted!

Comment: Well, I'm "old" to TeX, and like to encourage newcomers.  And I'm impressed with the structure and execution of the example that provides clarity to what's going on.  You may be new to LaTeX, but you obviously think analytically and are able to communicate your conclusions effectively.

Comment: Look at `usrguide3.pdf` to find how to avoid `environ` with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the vertical space by adding appropriate negative space. For example you can define:

```
\def\keeptheoremline{%
 \noindent \vskip-\prevdepth \hrule height0pt
 \vskip-\abovedisplayshortskip \vskip-\baselineskip
}
```

and use

```
\begin{lemma}\keeptheoremline
 \begin{equation} 
   L_b \circ L_a = L_{L_b(a)} \circ L_b.
 \end{equation}
\end{lemma}
```